# Как добавить/удалить класс в куки?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Пожалуйста, подскажите, как можно при: добавлении, удаление классов (при toggleClass например) сохранять результат после перезагрузки страницы. Я так понимаю, надо работать с куки.

К примеру вот код:

```
<script>
$('.menu-trigger').on('click', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    return false;
  });
</script>
```

Как сделать так, чтобы результат добавления/удаления сохранился?

Answer (score 0):

Не стоит использовать cookie для хранения данных и параметров конфигурации. Они не для этого, а для реализации хранения состояния в HTTP. Они постоянно пересылаются со всеми HTTP запросами и их количество на домен очень ограничено.

Лучше использовать LocalStorage:

```
$('.menu-trigger').on('click', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    localStorage.setItem('menu-trigger-class', 'active');
    return false;
});
```

Потом всегда можно получить сохранённое значение через `localStorage.getItem('menu-trigger-class');`;

Comment: что-то не работает

Comment: @VladimirRodichev что именно не работает и как?

Comment: Результат не сохраняется.

Comment: @VladimirRodichev без деталей сложно сказать, что именно пошло не так. У меня всё работает.

Comment: у меня работает только мой код. ваш - не работает. результат не сохраняется.

Comment: Сделал интерактивный пример: jsfiddle.net/shaukote/kcr67stn